# Adding numbers on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I'm trying to make a type of invoice.
Here's my problem : The invoice has various input boxes where the amount is typed by the user and there's "Total Charge"(input box) at the end of the list of those boxes. So what I want is that if some values(numeric) are filled in the the input boxes and a user click on the "Total Charge"(input box) the values are summed. How can I do it? I have used jQuery before. So, if possible can anyone explain how can  I do it in jQuery?

Script so far

```
$('.charge').blur(function () {
var totalocharges = 0;
$('.charge').each(function() {
    totalocharges += Number($(this).val());
});


$('#total_charges').val(totalocharges);
});
```

my view(just a part of it):

```
<div class="form-group  col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">          
    <input type="number" class="charge form-control" id="amount1" name="amount1" value="<?php echo set_value('amount1'); ?>" placeholder="amount" required>
  </div>

<div class="form-group  col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">          
    <input type="number" class="charge form-control" id="amount2" name="amount2" value="<?php echo set_value('amount2'); ?>" placeholder="amount" required>
  </div>

<div class="form-group  col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">          
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="total_charges" name="total_charges" value="<?php echo set_value('total_charges'); ?>" placeholder="net amount">
  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to ask questions here. One hint: Show some code. You likely want something that looks like `var total=0; $(".amount").each(function() { total += parseFloat(this.value)}); $("#total").val(total.toFixed(2));`

Comment: You might find some hints [here: How to conduct arithmetic operations in JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680032/how-to-conduct-arithmetic-operations-in-jquery).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this with jQuery.

In this example, your input boxes would have 'charge' class. And your total charge input the ID total-charges)

```
$('.charge').blur(function () {
    var total_charges = 0;
    $('.charge').each(function() {
        total_charges += Number($(this).val());
    });


    $('#total-charges').val(total_charges);
});​​​​​​​​
```

Here you have a working code sample:

https://jsfiddle.net/0e8emcbu/

If you want to activate it with a button, then it would be like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/8cmL29xt/

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL this is what i'm getting in the console of chrome.

Comment: as i can see your code works just fine on fiddle ! but it is not working when i integrate it with my view in codeigniter. my id for total charge input was "total_charges" and since the var is total_charges so i changed that to "totalocharges". I think that is not causing the issue :/

Comment: It should work because one is an HTML ID and the other a Javascript VAR. If you want you can post your code in order to check. That error should be related to syntax error in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an event listener to the "Total charge" input box. For example, you can use "focus" event.

```
$("#total_charge").on('focus', function(){

  //here you have to make calculations
  //get values on all required input boxes
  var value1 = $("#input_box1").val();
  //another value

  //sum (multiply, divide etc) values
  val result = value1 + value2 + ...l

  //change total_charge value
  $("#total_charge").val(result);
});
```

Comment: so do i have to write all the var values and select all the input boxes? don't you think that will make the code big and not effecient?

Comment: you can use an iterator - just use class="my_calc_inputs" like Javier Núñez proposed earlear.